# rules for makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

let's assume I have some Makefile for Unix

```
prog:a.o b.o c.o
    gcc a.o b.o c.o -o prog
a.o:a.c a.h b.h
    gcc -c a.c
b.o:b.c b.h
    gcc -c b.c
c.o:c.c c.h b.h
    gcc -c c.c
```

I read that if I change *.c file I must recompile only this file, but if I change *.h file I must recompile all files which are depending on my *.h file, after both cases anyway `I must link` all files from the beginning

`1)`let's assume that I change only b.h, so what do I need to do?
my variant is `make a.o b.o c.o` am I right?

`2)`let's assume that I change only c.c, so what do I need to do?
my variant is `make c.o` am I right?

and finally if I write `make c.o` for example my makefile `ONLY recompile c.o` but `what about linker`? I have only `gcc -c c.c` and not `-o`

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean 'what do I need to do?'. In every case, just run `make prog`, and let make figure it out, that's the whole point.

EDIT: If you're curious what make will do in each case, assuming you're running `make prog` every time, read on:

In case 1) b.h has changed, so anything depending on it (a.o, b.o and c.o) will be rebuilt, and prog will be relinked.

In case 2) c.o is only a direct dependency of c.c, so only c.o is built and prog relinked.

BTW, gcc can give you it's take on your dependencies by just running `gcc -MM *.c` in your project directory.

Comment: On a side note, if you're using gnu make, you can actually remove every line in your makefile starting with `gcc`. The default rules (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for make can figure out what you need for most simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases, you just do

```
make prog
```

or just

```
make
```

The idea of having the Makefile is that `make` can examine the dependencies, find out what's out of date, and do just the required recompilation (and no more).

If you change a `.c` file, obviously it's going to recompile that `.c` file, and because this updates a `.o` file on which `prog` depends, it will also relink `prog`.

If you change a `.h` file, this will trigger the recompilation of one or more `.c` files, which again will also cause `prog` to be relinked.